# R :: How to generate cases in a table that can occurr different times and with different names?

Tags: r, arrays, case, subset

I am trying to automatize an analysis of deltaCT for qPCR in my lab, basically I need to process a dataframe made like this

| gene_id | target_id | Cq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TATAB | EtOH | 26.03 |
| ROLG | EtOH | 26.12 |
| TATAB | aLA | 21.4 |
| ROLG | aLA | 21.9 |

What I want is that everytime i import this table, my code can make multiple sub_matrixes for each gene_id and for each target_id

EtOH

| gene_id | target_id | Cq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TATAB | EtOH | 26.03 |
| ROLG | EtOH | 26.12 |

aLA

| gene_id | target_id | Cq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TATAB | aLA | 21.4 |
| ROLG | aLA | 21.9 |

and for each gene_id

TATAB

| gene_id | target_id | Cq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TATAB | EtOH | 26.03 |
| TATAB | aLA | 21.4 |

ROLG

| gene_id | target_id | Cq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ROLG | EtOH | 26.12 |
| ROLG | aLA | 21.9 |

I can easily do that manually, but i would like to automatize it as in asking R to find all matching rows in "gene_id" column, and create an object with each one of these, that I can use later to work on Cq values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `group_split` from `dplyr` package:

You will get a list.
For example `target_id`. One way to access the first dataframe in this list is: `target_id[[1]]`.

Then same procedure for `gene_id`

```
library(dplyr)

target_id <- df %>% 
  group_split(target_id)

gene_id <- df %>% 
  group_split(gene_id)

target_id
target_id[[1]]
target_id[[2]]

# same as for gene_id
```

output:

```
> target_id
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    gene_id  : character
    target_id: character
    Cq       : double
  >
>[2]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  gene_id target_id    Cq
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 TATAB   aLA        21.4
2 ROLG    aLA        21.9

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  gene_id target_id    Cq
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 TATAB   EtOH       26.0
2 ROLG    EtOH       26.1

> target_id[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  gene_id target_id    Cq
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 TATAB   aLA        21.4
2 ROLG    aLA        21.9
> target_id[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  gene_id target_id    Cq
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 TATAB   EtOH       26.0
2 ROLG    EtOH       26.1
```

Comment: And I can automatize this by checking the number of unique strings in both, and using a for cycle?

Comment: It is already automatized. You don't need a foor loop